# Wordpress - Add post title to meta field query

Tags: php, advanced-custom-fields, wordpress

**Question: Is there a way to add the built-in `s=query` into a meta field query `OR` array?**

We want to query on both meta data **and** post title, for the purpose of a search form. Currently, adding the `s=query` prevents the `meta_query` from functioning (which it does so perfectly without).

**PHP**

```
// Our search request
$queryString = sanitize_text_field($_REQUEST['query']);

// List of ACF fields to loop through
$customFields = array('title', 'subtitle', 'page_content');

// Setup basic "OR" meta_query for ACF fields
$customFieldsMetaQuery = array(
  'relation' => 'OR'
);

// Insert given ACF fields into meta_query
foreach ($customFields as $field) {
  $customFieldsMetaQuery[] = array(
    'key'      => $field,
    'value'    => $queryString,
    'compare'  => 'LIKE',
  );
}

// Query Arguments
$args = array(
  'post_type'      => array('page'),
  's'              => $queryString, // This line clashes with 'meta_query'
  'meta_query'     => $customFieldsMetaQuery, // This line clashes with 's'
);

// Construct Query
$searchQuery = new WP_Query($args);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, in order to keep the original meta query structure like shown in [here](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/).

```
// Insert given ACF fields into meta_query
foreach ($customFields as $field) {
   $customFieldsMetaQuery[] = array(
'key'      => $field,
'value'    => $queryString,
'compare'  => 'LIKE',
 );
}

// Setup basic "OR" meta_query for ACF fields
$customFields = array(
'relation' => 'OR',
$customFieldsMetaQuery
);
```